# Variable isConnected is not changed

Tags: javascript, mysql, scope, mocha.js, chai

isConnected is supposed to be a variable to test if the database connection is successfull or not. Now in my DatabaseTest class I want to assert this isConnected variable. isConnected is declared in the database object, so it should be accessable via database.isConnected. But the value is not changed in the makeConnection() and closeConnection(). I suspect this is due to the fact that isConnected is no global variable. Also when I declare it as var isConnected just after the var mysql line it doesn't update it either.
Am I missing some basic scope fundamentals?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

//Database
var database = {

isConnected: false,

makeConnection: function(){

    var connectionString = {
        host: '192.168.1.3',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: 'secret',
        database: 'user_profile_database'
    };

    var activeConnection = mysql.createConnection(connectionString);
    activeConnection.connect(function(error){
            if(error){
                throw error;
            }
            console.log("Successfull connection!");
        });
        isConnected = true;
    return activeConnection;
},

closeConnection: function(activeConnection){
    activeConnection.end(function(error){
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }
        console.log("Successfull disconnetion!");
    });
    isConnected = false;
  }
}

module.exports = database;
```

So this is the test case:

```
var database = require('../Code/Database/Database');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

//Tests for the Database class.
describe("#Database", function(){

//Test for the makeConnection method
describe("#makeConnection", function(){

    it("should make a connection with the database", function(){
        expect(database.isConnected).to.be.false;
        var connection = database.makeConnection();
        expect(database.isConnected).to.be.true;
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: `isConnected` is a property of your object. You have to refer to that property via a reference to the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `makeConnetion()` and `closeConnection()` methods, you should refer to `isConnected` as `this.isConnected`.

For example:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

//Database
var database = {

isConnected: false,

makeConnection: function(){

    var connectionString = {
        host: '192.168.1.3',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: 'secret',
        database: 'user_profile_database'
    };

    var activeConnection = mysql.createConnection(connectionString);
    activeConnection.connect(function(error){
            if(error){
                throw error;
            }
            console.log("Successfull connection!");
        });
        this.isConnected = true; // instead of just isConnected
    return activeConnection;
},

closeConnection: function(activeConnection){
    activeConnection.end(function(error){
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }
        console.log("Successfull disconnetion!");
    });
    this.isConnected = false; // instead of just isConnected
  }
}

module.exports = database;
```

Comment: How did I overlook this? I remember trying this.property but probably had something else wrong as well. Thanks a lot!